# conversion to PHP, update and insert in subdocument

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having trouble converting the statement to php

Here is the structure of the data:

```
db.rooms.find({"_id" : "1620888265"}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : "1620888265",
    "start" : 1620988265,
    "end" : null,
    "users" : [
                {
                "name" : "owner",
                "score" : 0.9,
                "singin" : 1620895469
                },
                {
                "name" : "user",
                "singin" : 1620895769
                }
        ],
    "questions" : [
        {
            "id": 1
            "title" : "X",
            "released" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the command that works for me:

```
 db.rooms.updateOne({"_id" : "1620970325obn","questions.ident":2},{$set : {"questions.$.released":true,"questions.$.time":'1415'}});
```

Once translated to PHP (not working for me):

```
$rooms_db->updateOne(array("_id" => $room,"questions.ident"=>$ident), array ('$set'=>array('questions.$.released' => true,'questions.$.time'=>$time)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been that the variable "$ident" was a number, but for some reason PHP treated it as a String. This can be seen with `var_dump ($ident)` .

`"questions.ident"=>(int)$ident),` this fixed the problem